# Unable to use extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterValue for security reasons in jenkins

Tags: arrays, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

please find the error while trying to pass the parameters during build -

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterValue for security reasons; see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/
    at hudson.util.XStream2$BlacklistedTypesConverter.marshal(XStream2.java:541)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:264)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:251)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.ParametersAction#parameters for class hudson.model.ParametersAction
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:255)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:223)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:264)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:251)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#actions for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:255)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:223)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1026)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1015)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:988)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:195)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:2077)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl.forRun(EnvActionImpl.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl$Binder.getValue(EnvActionImpl.java:149)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl$Binder.getValue(EnvActionImpl.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.getProperty(CpsScript.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:354)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:202)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:2077)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl.forRun(EnvActionImpl.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl$Binder.getValue(EnvActionImpl.java:149)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl$Binder.getValue(EnvActionImpl.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.getProperty(CpsScript.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:456)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:354)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor629.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

We are stated to see security issue related to extended choice parameters in jenkins ,which gets json array as input. Please find the error . Can you please help on this. FYI There was no jenkins or plugins update done recently. This stared happening all of the sudden (2 weeks back) and all the "extended choice parameters" got deleted without any clue in jenkins build.

extended choice parameters VERSION - 0.78
jenkins VERSION - 2.263.1

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed by replacing the extended choice parameter jar file with the latest version which had fix to extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterValue parameters. Also, make sure to White list "export JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterValue" in .bash_profile of your jenkins machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).